# Delay in reading from specific database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an application written in VB.NET which reads data from an SQL Server 2008 R2.
At the time of login, user select one of the many database files (available in a dropdown list) and then keys in his username and password to login. While logging in, the application reads from a table in the selected database called 'strings' and a Do While loop put values in some 25-30 variables for creating working environment of the application.

I have put in a time tracking at beginning and end of the Do While loop and it shows that for one of the database, it takes 26 seconds to read all values and for another it takes 0 seconds (Since I am not tracking at mili-seconds level).

Ironically, the 'strings' table in database that takes 26 seconds has 125 rows and the database that takes 0 seconds has 159 rows. Apparently, the code is same, and the database structure is also a true replica (Both databases were generated using same script).

I have thought of all possibilities but not sure why there's such huge difference which delays login time of the user.

Can you please put some light on how I can figure this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without any specific information is rather difficult to find what is going on. To return about a hundred records should not take more the several tens of milliseconds, simple code usually has no performance impact.  It seems that the second server has a serious performance problem.

- Try to run your query from SQL Server Management Studio against both
  servers, check CPU load and free memory on slow server.
- Try to check network performance (ping or measure file download
  time).
- Try to run query directly on server.

Comment: Unfortunately the server is same. I have come to know that the database that has performance issue was originally built on SQL Server 2005. The SQL Server 2005 installation was later upgraded to SQL Server 2008 R2. The other database that is fast was built on SQL Server 2008 R2 itself. Can this be causing the issue?

Comment: @PrashantGupta: An upgrade itself probably does not deteriorate performance. However it seems that the database is rather old. The indexes in it can be in a bad shape see Rebuild an Index technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874(v=sql.105).aspx. It can be useful to consult appropriate server admin to do database maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and comparison between the two database files, I found that the 'initial size' of the database file (mdf) and the log file (ldf) were very different.

The fast database's mdf and ldf files were more than 200 MB each. However the slow database were 11 MB and 16MB respectively. I changed the slow database files 'initial size' to the same values as fast database using Microsoft SQL Management Studio, stopped and started the SQL Server and Whoa! There is no performance difference now.

Putting this as an answer just in case someone find it useful.